# Why I see only 100 maxmimum total concurrent requests whem the limit is 1000?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, instance

[Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Qfo.jpg)
[Invocations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKoVd.jpg)

By default amazon says that there are can be 1000 instances for free plan.

But when i've write a highload stress-testing with multiple requests at the same time, only 100 instances are allocated. Why this is happen?

I've expect that all 1000 instances will be allocated in free plan.

There is config file:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 50
    MemorySize: 3000
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true

Resources:
  InferenceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        Inference:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /predict
            Method: post
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./app
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1

  ApplicationResourceGroup:
    Type: AWS::ResourceGroups::Group
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      ResourceQuery:
        Type: CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
  ApplicationInsightsMonitoring:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application
    Properties:
      ResourceGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      AutoConfigurationEnabled: 'true'
    DependsOn: ApplicationResourceGroup
Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  InferenceApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Inference function
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/predict/"
  InferenceFunction:
    Description: Inference Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt InferenceFunction.Arn
  InferenceFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Inference function
    Value: !GetAtt InferenceFunctionRole.Arn
```

There is Python AWS Lambda handler

```py
import json

from analyzer.model import Model

model_file = '/opt/ml/model'
model = Model(model_file, device="cpu")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sample = event['body']
    result =model(sample)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(
            {
                "predicted_label": result.value
            }
        )
    }
```

There is Docker file

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY . .

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the code, or the way you are executing it.  But you haven't shown us those details, so there is no way for us to help...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this is a relatively new AWS account with minimal usage and  billing history. You are therefore experiencing reduced concurrency, per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html):

> New AWS accounts have reduced concurrency and memory quotas. AWS raises these quotas automatically based on your usage. You can also request a quota increase.